# keyboard with numeric and basic math operations for an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-inputtype

How I can have this keyboard

[image]

for an EditText?

I tried with InputType but I could not have this keyboard.

I have created this example that shows the answers are not solving the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!--number-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="hint"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!--numberDecimal|numberSigned-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:digits="0123456789.+-*/%()"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout" />

    <!--numberPassword-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the resulted keyboards for the first two input types are same and they are like:
[image]

and the last one is like:

[image]

Comment: please, attach the code of this edittext and try to test on another device if such problem exists on them

Comment: I improved the question.

Comment: If you want to make a calculator, then you should implement your own keyboard, AFAIK. It's not difficult, just a GridView with some TextViews. And, yes, TextViews do respond to click.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for displaying only numbers:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

Or use this for displaying numbers when you use the EditText for Passwords:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword" />
```

Please also understand that mostly every phone has another keyboard design, so you may not get the exact keyboard you mentioned in you picture

Comment: I have tried these and they are not giving the same as I have the screen shots:

Comment: I understand that but it depends on what device you are running the code. What emulator or device are you using?

Comment: I use Pixel with API 27

Comment: From what device is your first picture?

Comment: As I mentioned, It is from android emulator of `Pixel API 27`. If the inputType is text you can change the keyboard with `123?`

Comment: No I mean the picture of the keyboard you want to have

Comment: If the inputType is text you can change the keyboard with `123?` and then `1234`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
```