# Full number keyboard with + - * / ( ) = keys

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to show the keyboard like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHis3.png) on edit text focus.

How to show the soft keyboard in the layout shown in the image? I want the + - / * ( ) keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keyboard with numeric and basic math operations for an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696230/keyboard-with-numeric-and-basic-math-operations-for-an-edittext)

Comment: @javdromero The above question is same as mine, but there are no right answers

Answer (score 0):

All you need is input type! So in your XML file. Add this line to your editText:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Also, you can use other types based on your needs, like:`text`,`phone`,`date`,`password`,etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code into you `EditText`

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

[image]

Also, if you want to show those special characters, it will depend of the current keyboard of the phone, but generally after press in `*#` it will apper

[image]